# OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0"

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I want to translate the texts in a csv file into English using the GPT 4 model, but I constantly get the following error. Even though I updated the version, I continue to get the same error.

```
import openai
import pandas as pd
import os
from tqdm import tqdm


openai.api_key = os.getenv("API")

def translate_text(text):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",  # GPT-4 modeli
        prompt=f"Translate the following Turkish text to English: '{text}'",
        max_tokens=60
    )
    # Yeni API yapısına göre yanıtın alınması
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

df = pd.read_excel('/content/3500-turkish-dataset-column-name.xlsx')

column_to_translate = 'review'

df[column_to_translate + '_en'] = ''

for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
    translated_text = translate_text(row[column_to_translate])
    df.at[index, column_to_translate + '_en'] = translated_text

df.to_csv('path/to/your/translated_csvfile.csv', index=False)
```

```
 0%|          | 0/3500 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
APIRemovedInV1                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-337b5b6f4d32> in <cell line: 29>()
     28 # Her satırdaki metni çevir ve yeni sütuna kaydet
     29 for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
---> 30     translated_text = translate_text(row[column_to_translate])
     31     df.at[index, column_to_translate + '_en'] = translated_text
     32 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/lib/_old_api.py in __load__(self)

APIRemovedInV1: 

You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. 

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
```

Even though I updated the OpenAI package version, I get the same error.

Comment: the error is _because_ you are using a newer version. you will have to update your function to use openai's updated api. or you can run `openai migrate` as the error suggests

Comment: How can I do this via colab?

Answer (score 10):

#### Problem

**The method name you're trying to use doesn't work with the OpenAI Python SDK version `1.0.0` or newer.**

The old SDK (i.e., version `0.28`) works with the following method name:

```
client.Completion.create
```

The new SDK (i.e., version `1.0.0` or newer) works with the following method name:

```
client.completions.create
```

*Note: Be careful because the API is case-sensitive (i.e., `client.Completions.create` will not work with the new SDK version).*

#### Solution

Try this:

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

completion = client.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
  prompt="Say this is a test",
  max_tokens=7,
  temperature=0
)

print(completion.choices[0].text)
```

Comment: <ipython-input-32-467fdcabfcd9> in translate_text(text)
      9 # Çeviri yapacak fonksiyon
     10 def translate_text(text):
---> 11     response = openai.completion.create(
     12         model="text-davinci-003",  # GPT-4 modeli
     13         prompt=f"Translate the following Turkish text to English: '{text}'",

AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'completion'

This time I got this error too

Comment: @KaanTiftikci it is `completions`, not `completion`. notice the `s` at the end.

Comment: I would be very happy if you could help me by reaching me via linkedin :) https://www.linkedin.com/in/kaantiftikci/